# How to merge two dataframes and add columns to the new dataset?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

**I have one dataframe that looks like this(sender is the column name):**

```
|sender|
sender1
sender2
sender3
sender4
```

**I have another dataframe that looks like this:**

```
| sender |_time | type
sender1,  12/9/2020, email
sender1,  12/4/2020, user
sender2,  12/9/2020, email
sender1,  12/9/2020, email
sender5,  12/9/2020, email
```

I want to merge these two dataframes together by the sender column and then add a few new columns- count, date_added. Data added would be the current timestamp when the script is ran and the count would be the number of times the sender column matched.

**Based on the above two datasets, the output would be like this:**

```
 |sender | count | date_added
 sender1 , 3 , <current_timestamp>
sender2 , 1 , <current_timestamp>
sender3 , 0 , <current_timestamp>
sender4 , 0 , <current_timestamp>
```

**Here is my code so far:**

```
   senders = ['sender1','sender2','sender3','sender4']
 df1 = pd.DataFrame(senders, columns=['sender'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(reader)

df_right = pd.merge(df1, df2, on='sender', how='right')
```

The above code works however I am confused as to how to add the two columns to the output as stated above. Any ideas or suggestions would help.

Comment: why do you merge? df1 does not contain any new information.

Answer (score 0):

get the count:

```
df_right['count'] = df_right.groupby('sender').count()
```

add the time:

```
df_right['time'] = current_time
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'sender':['sender1','sender2','sender3','sender4']})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'sender': {0: 'sender1',
  1: 'sender1',
  2: 'sender2',
  3: 'sender1',
  4: 'sender5'},
 'time': {0: '12/9/2020',
  1: '12/4/2020',
  2: '12/9/2020',
  3: '12/9/2020',
  4: '12/9/2020'},
 'type': {0: 'email', 1: 'user', 2: 'email', 3: 'email', 4: 'email'}})

c  = df2.loc[df2['sender'].isin(df['sender'].values)].groupby('sender').size().reset_index()

output = df.merge(c, on='sender', how='left').fillna(0)
output['date_added'] = pd.datetime.now()
output.columns = ['sender','count','date_added']
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```py
(df1.merge(df2, how='left').groupby('sender')
 .type.count()
 .reset_index(name='count')
 .assign(date_added=pd.Timestamp.now())
)
```

Output:

```
    sender  count                 date_added
0  sender1      3 2020-12-09 19:45:48.013140
1  sender2      1 2020-12-09 19:45:48.013140
2  sender3      0 2020-12-09 19:45:48.013140
3  sender4      0 2020-12-09 19:45:48.013140
```